# iOS - Catching When NSXMLParser Fails

Tags: ios, xml, uitableview, rss, nsxmlparser

In my app, I'm using `NSXMLParser` to show all the articles in Drudge Report's RSS feed in a `UITableView`. Sometimes, Drudge Report's RSS feed xml online gets broken due to errors on their side when they sometimes add feeds incorrectly. When this happens, my `NSXMLParser` doesn't even bother to try and parse the xml file, and I end up with a blank `UITableView`.

The bad part about it is that the `NSXMLParser` doesn't even send a message to its error handling delegate methods, which means I don't currently have a way of telling the user that getting the articles from Drudge Report's RSS feed failed.

Is there a way I can get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my own problem using the following code:

```
if ([parser parse]) {
        NSLog(@"PARSING WAS SUCCESSFUL");
        NSLog(@"NUMBER OF FEEDS THO: %lu", (unsigned long)feeds.count);
        [self hideLoadingCoverView];
    }
else {
    [self displayFailureToGetArticles];
}
```

Apparently, calling the `parse` method on the `NSXMLParser` returns a boolean as to whether it was successful or not in parsing the online xml document. Just in case anyone else comes across this issue, this is how I solved it.